# Getting Unique Data Based on Two Columns and Date

Tags: sql, sas, data-manipulation

I am new to SAS (and Proc SQL) and I am working this out as an exercise to improve my familiarity with SAS, but can't seem to get the correct solution.

I have resort data for two neighboring resorts that contains a guest identifier, resort identifier, when the person was admitted into the resort, and when they left. I have already sorted the data by guest identifier, admission date, and leave date. The data looks something like this:

```
ID Resort Admission_Date Leave_Date
1  B      15SEP2020      24SEP2020
1  A      24SEP2020      01OCT2020
1  B      25SEP2020      27SEP2020
1  B      28DEC2020      29DEC2020
2  B      07FEB2020      09FEB2020
2  A      09FEB2020      22FEB2020
3  B      26DEC2019      29DEC2019
3  B      30JAN2021      23FEB2021
3  A      23FEB2021      12MAR2021
3  B      13APR2021      16APR2021
3  B      05MAY2021      07MAY2021
```

My goal here is to identify those guests that went from resort A to resort B (and vice versa). I realize that some guests visited both resorts multiple times. To avoid this issue of multiple resort visits I would like to summarize the data so that we only have the first "switch" between hotels. In other words, once a guest switches from resort A to B (or from B to A) we do not care if they go back to the first resort.
Thus, the end dataset should look something like this:

```
ID Resort Admission_Date Leave_Date
1  B      15SEP2020      24SEP2020
1  A      24SEP2020      01OCT2020
2  B      07FEB2020      09FEB2020
2  A      09FEB2020      22FEB2020
3  B      26DEC2019      29DEC2019
3  A      23FEB2021      12MAR2021
```

I realize that this may have a simple solution, but I am not able to come up with it on my own at this time so any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a homework question? I've seen it a few times in the last few weeks.

Comment: Not homework, I'm working through some self taught SAS/SQL tutorials

Comment: Can you link the tutorial (might help with answers, and better yet would help future users!)  Also - do you _only_ want to look for a SQL solution, or a data step solution is okay?  Finally - post whatever you've tried for this, so we can guide that better.